# Could you explain this deep-cloning function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here is a function that returns a deep clone of whatever you pass to it.

Whether or not you think it is the greatest function ever, could you help me to understand it?

I can see it is creating a new variable that replicates the source constructor, and then iterates recursively... but I can't quite see how it is working.

```
 function clonator (source) {
  if (source === null || typeof source !== 'object')
    return source;

  const temp = source.constructor();

  for (let key in source) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
      source['isClone'] = null;
      temp[key] = clonator(source[key]);
      delete source['isClone'];
    }
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: Here is my personal favorite cloning function, `deepCopy()` [https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/util.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/util.js)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the function missed the use of `isClone` property which prevents to clone an object forever.

Basically this function gets any type of data and makes a not null check and a type check to exclude non data types without keys.

Then it takes a new constructor, for example to get an array as target.

Finally it loops over all enumerable keys and takes a check for own keys, which prevents prototypes to be copied.

The assignment of `isClone` prevents a copy of the same part again and again and stops recursive calls.

Now it need to assign the value and deletes the leftover of `isClone`.

```js
function clonator (source) {
    if (source === null || typeof source !== 'object' || source.isClone === null)
        return source;

    const temp = source.constructor();

    for (let key in source) {
        console.log('key', key);
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
            source['isClone'] = null;
            temp[key] = clonator(source[key]);
            delete source['isClone'];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

var a = { foo: 42, bar: [1, 2] };
a.b = a;                          // create circular reference

var b = clonator(a);

console.log(b.b.b.foo); // 42
console.log(b.b.b.bar); // [1, 2]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```